# A several billion dollars project to stop people from sneezing, besides full hazmat suits?

Tags: science-based, biology

As the government stopped believing in Hammerwoman, a heroine with the power of a hammer like intelligence and agility...etc, they turned to science to save them from the dreaded Sneezator

The super villain is threatening to unleash his horrors upon the world unless he is handed control of the world so he can destroy it then rule it.

The US president gathered the brightest minds of the nation to come up with a defense strategy to protect the nation from their dreaded foe.

His ability can cover around 300 square km and unless people are completely protected with full hazmat suits then his power gets to them and they will sneeze. Thus his rise to the forefront of  villainy in the world was inevitable.

As far as I know sneezing is mostly particles or something similar or an allergic reaction or a virus...etc. I just have the overall thing be only resistant to full hazmat suits. This way it is not total magic but not exact science. Even skin exposure to air infected with the power gets people to sneeze.

So. The most obvious method is full hazmat suits for the whole nation **but I want anything else** because I want the totally serious discussion between the brightest minds in the US to cover all bases besides that.

All sorts of suggestions are welcome from genetic engineering to mass producing and distributing a sneeze inhibitor or anything. But I want a real scientific thing. Like if the problem was real for whatever reason.

Bonus points if the project is insanely expensive as you can see the story is obviously serious.

Comment: What if Sneezator goes to China, India, Russia, Canada, Japan, Nigeria, Italy or anywhere else?

Comment: @VictorStafusa.
I have a scene in the story that's about that.
None US country: what are our defense strategies against super villain X?
Advisor: I don't know man. When was the last time you had a super villain leave the US and cause havoc somewhere else?
Good point.
Basically the fact that the villains in the story only operate in the US is a part of the very serious tone of the story

Comment: What's the actual mechanism by why people are forced to sneeze?  Could you just plug up people's noses, so they don't get particles up the nose and the resulting tickling sensations that trigger sneezing?  (not that this is a great solution ... mouth breathing causes other problems, and would result in more coughing)

Comment: "As far as I know", well, your hazmat suit won't stop the [photic sneeze reflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photic_sneeze_reflex).

Comment: @Joe,
Like I said mostly airborne that requires either skin exposure or of course getting inhaled. 
That's why hazmat suits are useful but only full hazmat suits.
It's insane I know of course.

Comment: @pipe,
Well. Right after that I said "As far as I know sneezing is mostly"
And later described the process of infection as breathing or skin exposure.
I read about that but found it impractical to introduce to the story for obvious reasons. That's why I thought to forget about all other methods and have the villains main power work like that.
But appreciated

Comment: Kill the bad guy? Or put him in 1 Hazmat suit - and lock away. Problem solved.

Comment: What "magic" is used to make people sneeze?  The countermeasure should act on that mechanism, not on the normal biological sneeze action.  He has an "ability".  Find your own person with a similar "ability" to cancel it, or reverse it back to the sender.

Comment: If the supervillain can put a substance on someone's skin that causes them to sneeze, they're not using any of the known mechanisms for causing sneezes. If the substance has to enter their nose, then a standard N95 mask will be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Spike the town's water with anti histamines

As a bonus the us president gets to give tonnes of money to his friends (sponsers) in big pharma.

Buy tonnes of brand name anti histamines. Dump in towns water supply. Sneezing power is stopped or greatly reduced.

As a bonus, all allergic reactions are reduced, so hayfever symptoms disappear, mild food allergies are reduced or cleared. This could be a net positive for the community.

Comment: As much as I want this to be a good idea, there's probably plenty of people allergic to the various medicines. Also, anti-histamines tend to come with the drawback of making people drowsy and a warning to not operate heavy machinery. That could bring down construction, machine operators in manufacturing, prevent people from driving, and so much more. Even caffeine won't fix that side effect, but people will try.

Answer (score 7):

### Block the nerve sensations that carry the sneeze trigger to the brain.

I suspect that an ultra-long duration local anesthesia could be used to block the [Anterior ethmoidal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anterior_ethmoidal_nerve) nerve. While I am not aware of anything currently approved in any country that can serve as a long-duration local anesthetic, a re-engineering of existing time-release drug mechanisms could suffice for perhaps weekly or even longer injection cycles (e.g., Bydureon has weekly injections due to time release).

The head is crowded with nerves, so a very precise injection site would be needed because you don't want to paralyze other parts of the head, so this process would be expensive and likely require some imaging or probing assistance for the precise location.

The deadening sensation from nerve blocking can be very annoying, so this would not be popular unless it is less annoying than the sneezing. Aversion to needles makes it undesirable, esp. considering the injection site. Blocking normal nerve function is also hazardous because it can mask medical conditions.

Perhaps one could conjecture a nano-technology based equivalent, but that it clearly not someday that we will be able to do in the near future.

Sneezing is not just annoying, it is functional because it clears out the dust, etc. causing the irritation. So you really should not shut down the sneezing response either.

Any mass dosing of medications will have downsides. Some people are allergic to anesthetics, although there are a number of available options. Others could be treated with anti-histamines, e.g. Claritin, but there will be a different set of problems in some patients. Other medications might be necessary in other patients, each with it's associated risks

Comment: "Blocking normal nerve function is also hazardous because it can mask medical conditions." - such as a highly infectious disease whose only reliable symptom is the loss of smell but which also has a decent chance to straight up kill you.

Answer (score 4):

#### Fusion-powered mitochondria

Sneezing is an operation of the human respiratory system. If we can remove the respiratory system, we can make sneezing impossible.

The human respiratory system exists because it is necessary for replenishing oxygen in the bloodstream to supply aerobic respiration. By reengineering human mitochondria to replenish ATP by fusing hydrogen instead of oxidizing pyruvate, we could obviate the need for the respiratory system entirely. With the respiratory system then surgically removed, a subject would be entirely immune to the Sneezator's powers.

Other metabolic pathways and biological processes would likely need to be redesigned as well, and talking might have to be replaced with a phone app or something, but for total protection against the Sneezator, your characters might consider the project worthwhile.

Answer (score 4):

### Snipers

Train them to fire within hazmat suits. That shouldn't be too hard, since they are already trained to work from military [NBC suits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBC_suit) with gas masks. Then again, NBC gear might be the equivalent of the hazmat suit, since they perform the same protective functions.

At the same time, create a network of detectors that will track the edges of the sneezing outbreak. Once you know the bounds of the problem, you can guess roughly where the center of it is, and assume the Villain is there.

Once you have this information, send in the snipers. Good snipers can hit a target at a mile (1.6km). Really good snipers can hit targets at around 2 miles (3.2km). You just need to get them "close enough" to take out this bad guy.

It helps if they are doing something as silly as floating above the buildings in a "god pose". Being out in the open and moving slowly is a perfect shot for snipers.

### Bombs

If the target is hunkered down in a building, snipers might still be able to take the shot, but if they can get positive ID, you can send in a variety of rockets or smart bombs that'll level the building. Even artillery has [GPS guided shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M982_Excalibur) and can fire from 14 miles (23km) away that'll drop the building on this bad guy.

### Fighter jets

If the target still manages to fly away, send in fighter jets. They have their own contained air supply and can fly upwards of Mach 1, as well as fire air to air missiles from a couple miles away, with the missiles flying at upwards of Mach 2.

### Airborne laser

If even the jets are too slow, use an [airborne laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_YAL-1). That can engage targets at up to 600km. This has the advantage of being able to follow a target by simply moving it's mirror, so it can aim at something going at nearly any speed. The limiting factor here is the targeting system.

Even if you don't vaporize the Villain and simply damage them, other forces can finish them off. Slow them down with the laser, smack them around with missiles, and finish them off with a dozen snipers. Maybe run them over with a tank or two, just to be sure. Or just continually hit the stationary target with the laser again until the bad guy is completely BBQ'd.

### Repurcussions

What about the [Geneva convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geneva_Conventions), you say? That only applies to [foreign forces or where declarations of war are made](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/geneva_conventions_and_their_additional_protocols). If the Villain is a citizen and neither side declares war, there's not much that can be done to apply those laws. If someone decides they do apply, the military can just throw someone under the bus and court martial them, then bury the trial, the results, and the accused in red tape and security clearances so that no one can find out what happened for 50+ years.

### Conclusion

Even with today's technology, we should be able to take care of this Super Villain. And regardless of how stupid/inept the military is made to look like when dealing with superpowered individuals in the movies, they really do know how to take down a target and ramp up the level of force used proportionally to what's necessary to deal with a threat. The US military, specifically, should be well equipped to deal with nearly any powered individual or "metahuman" below the Superman level. I didn't even suggest using a 5kt tactical nuke, which could be dropped from a bomber or possibly artillery.

Oh, wait... I just did. Never mind.

Comment: It's hard to see how this solution could cost multi-billion dollars, but it sounds otherwise effective.

Comment: @GaryWalker, I took that "several billion" as an upper limit for the cost. Besides, with any military action, the costs skyrocket quickly. A couple \$100k missiles here, a few \$75k artillery rounds there, dozens of fighters in the air, one multi-million dollar mini-nuke, dozens of companies of ground soldiers, and refitting a decommissioned and totally scrapped flying laser system will quickly add up to a billion or more. Sure, if the sniper(s) worked right away, it might only be a \$50k price tag, but a good story doesn't usually end that easily.

Comment: @GaryWalker This is government we are talking about, because the project has a multi-billion dollar budget assigned to it; someone will figure out how to spend it all.  My guess is that you spend a few thousand dollars addressing the immediate problem, a few million dollars on special projects aimed at planning for future metahuman threats, and then a few billion dollars on what various interested parties can pocket out of the deal.